# Django 2.0 queryset display "object (1)" not display value

Tags: python, django-queryset

I want to display value from column `"sett_name"`, the value is (cisco and mikrotik). but what is displayed on html is `"c_Setting object (1) and c_Setting object (2)"`.

I've tried same code on python 2.7 with django 1.8. It works but when I try on python 3 with django 2.1.7 it does not work (I already modified the code to python3)

Here is `model.py` script :

```
class Ip(models.Model):
    ipaddr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.ipaddr
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ip address : %s: , vendor : %s' % (self.ipaddr, self.vendor)
class c_Setting(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'autonet_setting'
    sett_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sett_name
```

Here is `form.py` script :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Connect, Ip, c_Setting as settings
class IpForm(ModelForm):
    vendor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=settings.objects.all().order_by('sett_name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Ip
        fields = ['ipaddr','vendor']
class SettingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = settings
        fields = [
            'sett_name',
                        ...
                        ...
                ]
...
...
...
```

here is the html file :

```
{{ ipform.management_form }} 
{% for form in ipform %}
...
...
form.vendor
...
...
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the `view.py` script :

```
...
...
ipform = IpFormset()
return render(request, 'config/code_based.html', {'form': formm, 'logins': Connect.objects.all(), 'ipform': ipform, 'status': status })
...
...
```

like I said before it display `"c_Setting object (1) and c_Setting object (2)"` not `"mikrotik and cisco"`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `__str__` method, like on IP, rather than a `__unicode__` one

Comment: thank its solve my problem, between django 1.8 and django 2.0 has different like that? because when i running my code on django 1.8 its works

Comment: No, the difference is between Python 2 and Python 3.